'The specified module could not be found. after adding c++ dll in WinRt component and using WinRt in UWP
I have created a c++ library then added this to the WinRt successfully, setting all the linker input directory, the header file directory in visual studio for WinRt, and and referencing this winrt .winmd file in the uwp, now accessing the runtime class in the WinRt is causing issue

here are all three projects

Probably a duplicate of this.

@IInspectable i was able to add the c++/winrt to uwp successfully and run it, my main objective is to add a c++ lib/dll to c++/winrt and then use it in the uwp after doing this only i got the above exception i mentioned

I think you need to modify your csproj or look your nuggets packages for patch this issue

After wrapping my c++ library(.lib) in the winrt, and after referencing the winrt in the uwp still one thing was missing i need to copy the that C++ Dll in the executables of the the uwp which will be under the project folder \bin\x86\Debug\AppX
